# Does $\alpha$ for Tukey change like it does for Bonferroni?

Tags: confidence-interval, bonferroni, tukey-hsd-test

If you are trying to find confidence intervals, how does $\alpha$ for Tukey and Bonferroni differ? I understand that for Bonferroni the $\alpha$ is divided by the number of groups; however, does the $\alpha$ change when using Tukey?

Answer (score 1):

The [Tukey honest significant difference test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) keeps the desired family-wise error rate (FWER) at the desired value $\alpha$ by adjusting the *distribution* against which test statistics are compared. Instead of comparing test statistics against a t-distribution, the comparisons are against a [Studentized range distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range_distribution) that takes into account the number of pairwise comparisons being made.

The Bonferroni correction, in contrast, uses standard t-tests and then adjusts $\alpha$ for the individual tests to correct for multiple comparisons. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9425/28500) for discussion and links on when each of these approaches might be preferred. (Don't forget that the [Holm modification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method) to the Bonferroni correction provides the same FWER control with potentially greater power.)

Comment: Yes, you can find the implicit $\alpha$ for the Tukey comparisons by equating the Tukey critical value (chosen as the one that multiplies the s.e. of the estimated parameter) to $t_{1-\alpha/2}$, then solving for $\alpha$.  The resulting value will not be as small as the Bonferroni $\alpha/k$.